# Remove the HTML tags from the email, and desing the email body

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I have the following php code:

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="<html><body>
<span style='background-color: #cdcdcd'>
text: $name
</span>
text: $phone
<span style='background-color: #cdcdcd'>
text: $email
</span>
text: $message </html><body/>";
$recipient = "email@email.com";
$subject = "text text text ";
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

The problem is that wehn I recieve the email I see all the HTML tags in the email body, and the email isn't styling.

My question is how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually setting the Content-type header in the email headers variable

```
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Also go for exclusively single quotes, or double quotes when concatenating strings

Comment: I'll note it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need `$headers` for `text/html` not `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

If you don't get a better answer, I'll improve mine later. Short on time at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try it -

Remove line

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and replace

```
$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

by

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```